# Using a function to filter rows rather than creating separate dataframe copies

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to define a function passing column having specific rows' values.

Dataset:

```
Col1             Nam1    Nam2
Rare              12      2
Frequent          32      24
Not Frequent      43      42
...
```

I would like to group by the values for `Rare, Frequent` and `Not Frequent`, separately.

I did this:

```
df_rare=df[df['Col1'] == 'Rare'].copy()

rare= df_rare.groupby(['Nam1','Nam2'])['Nam1'].count()
```

How can I pass as parameter only values that are equal to `Rare/Frequent/Not Frequent` instead of creating three different datasets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add col1 in groupby key , then you have multiple index with Col1 level as first

```
rare = df.groupby(['Col1','Nam1','Nam2'])['Nam1'].count()
```

Comment: even better! I did not think of this option. Thank you @YOBEN_S (I have to wait for a few minutes more before marking your answer).